# Command prompt after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, command-line, upgrade

I've upgraded to 15.10 and now after the splash screen it goes to the command prompt.

Various apt-get commands all say "cannot resolve za.archive.ubuntu.com"

When I try to load from previous versions in the GRUB Advanced menu I get the same thing, except for <3.x which freezes.

`startx` resulted in colourful lines all over the sceen

Please help

Comment: It's not connecting to the net at all

Comment: You could (should?) use `sudo systemctl start graphical.target` instead of `startx`

Comment: Thanks.

sudo systemctl start graphical.target does nothing. Just retuns to next pompt

Comment: I was able to run dpkg --configure -a and now I can boot to low graphics mode (normal boot gives me a screen full of colourful lines), but I get an alert saying that my screen, graphics card, and input device settings can't be detected. I get the option to reconfigure my graphics with two options (backed up or default). Selecting either just returns me to the same options.

Comment: Gave up - did a fresh install of 14.04. Sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as you gave up and reinstalled, there's no chance to validate possible future answers.

Comment: @ByteCommander: next time use the "problem want away all by itself" instead of a custom close reason.  **;-)**

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW I just wanted to emphasize that the problem did not go away, it just became irreproducible/unverifiable.

Comment: Oh, well...  You succeeded!  **;-)**

Comment: Just a bit more on why I decided to give up. When running various commands to try to fix things I kept getting "File or directory not found" errors. These were for the display, networking, etc. All over the place. It seemed clear that something went very wrong in the upgrade process with various essential system files not being created.